# push notification not displayed (properly) if left in notification drawer for a period of time

Tags: notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

Using IBM MFP 7.0 I've got push notifications working for a hybrid app for Android and iOS.

**Except** if the user has the app closed and doesn't take action right away.

If the user leaves the notification for 10+ minutes (actually, it looks like 2 minutes was enough on iPhone, at least), the following happens:

- on Android: no message is displayed (there is no message waiting when the app is opened)

  - UPDATE: seems to happen only when the user has just installed a new apk but hasn't yet opened it when the push arrives
- on iOS: the message is displayed, but instead of the `alert` text from the message, what looks like a JSON object is in its place:

  ```
  {"body":"my alert text","action-loc-key":null}
  ```

Again, if the app is open/running, the message is always displayed correctly.
If the app is closed, but the user opens it immediately upon receiving the notification, the message is displayed correctly.
It is only when the user leaves the message for a while and then tries to open the app that this happens.

Is this expected behavior?
Is there some way I can program my `onMessage` handler so that it can detect the format of `props.alert` and extract the text properly?
Do I need to do something different for Android and iOS?

UPDATE: I'm checking for `props.alert.body` and using it if it exists, if it doesn't, I'm following the docs and just using `props.alert`.

Comment: How are you opening the application, from the app icon or from the notification center?

Comment: from the notification center

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this behavior with the sample application provided by IBM, or only with your custom application?

Comment: I don't have that custom app - it requires Eclipse, we're just using the cli. Does it work with the sample app for you? (From an app developer perspective, it's the same code that's being called whether the user opens the notification right away, or waits 2 minutes, so "try with the sample app" seems like a red herring.)

Comment: The provided sample application will work whether it is built using the CLI or Eclipse. I am not infront of a workstation to test, hence I am asking you to do so, as the one who asks this question...

Comment: Looks like the Android issue only happens if the push arrives before the user has opened the app after installing a new version of the apk ... also, I've worked around the iPhone issue by checking for the object and using it if it's there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a product defect w/out a local workaround.
In such cases you need to open an IBM PMR (support ticket) for the development team to investigate and provide a fix.